# Может ли несквозное отверстие называться прорехой?

Tags: названия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли назвать дыру на тапке прорехой? И вообще может ли дыра не на предмете одежды (в стене например) называться прорехой?

Comment: В стене - пролом, брешь. Прореха - прорезь, прорезать можно ткань, но не стену.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно, дыра в тапке может.

Прореха - дыра на одежде или на ином предмете из ткани. Это словарь.

А в стене - нет.

Но если в кавычках, то можно и ко стене употребить.